# How to create an invoice progrmatically in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to create or generate invoice automatically in the backend through programming when ever the user places an order. I tried a lot using the online  examples but with no result.

If I use the mageplaza tutorials, then it shows error while clearing the cache.
Is there any free module for this?

Can any one help me to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if your question will not solve.

Comment: Im very new to magento, U replied  to my question . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can u please let me know, what are the essential files or folders except,module.xml and registration.php

Comment: You can take reference from here : http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-create-a-magento-2-module-393

Comment: tq for ur support.

Answer (score 4):

Create a controller file and add this below code :

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Controller;

class CreateInvoice extends Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService
     */
    protected $_invoiceService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction
     */
    protected $_transaction;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = 1; //order id for which want to create invoice
        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if($order->canInvoice()) {
            $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
            $invoice->register();
            $invoice->save();
            $transactionSave = $this->_transaction->addObject(
                $invoice
            )->addObject(
                $invoice->getOrder()
            );
            $transactionSave->save();
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice); //send notification code
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about invoice #%1.', $invoice->getId())
            )
            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
            ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code its a working code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000009');
//OR
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load('1');


if ($order->canInvoice()) {
    $invoice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService')->prepareInvoice($order);

    if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an invoice without products.')
                );
    }

    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
    $invoice->register();

    $transaction = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

    $transaction->save();

    $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice); // Send Invoice email

    $order->addStatusHistoryComment(__('Invoice generated #%1.', $invoice->getId()))->setIsCustomerNotified(true)->save();
}
```

Use of Object manager is not recommended, you need to use this on controller or any observer.

Answer (score 2):

Full code in controller file with content below :

```
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Controller\Invoice;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService;

class SaveInvoice extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_coreOrder;
    protected $invoiceSender;
    protected $shipmentSender;
    protected $shipmentFactory;
    protected $registry;
    private $invoiceService;

    public function __construct(    
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $coreOrder,
        Registry $registry,
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
        ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);  
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        $this->_coreOrder = $coreOrder;   
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $this->shipmentSender = $shipmentSender;
        $this->shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare shipment
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment|false
     */
    protected function _prepareShipment($invoice)
    {
        $invoiceData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice');

        $shipment = $this->shipmentFactory->create(
            $invoice->getOrder(),
            isset($invoiceData['items']) ? $invoiceData['items'] : [],
            $this->getRequest()->getPost('tracking')
        );

        if (!$shipment->getTotalQty()) {
            return false;
        }

        return $shipment->register();
    }
    /**
     * Save invoice
     * We can save only new invoice. Existing invoices are not editable
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('invoice');
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_id');
        if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setCommentText($data['comment_text']);
        }
        try {
            $invoiceData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('invoice', []);
            $invoiceItems = isset($invoiceData['items']) ? $invoiceData['items'] : [];
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
            $order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            if (!$order->getId()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The order no longer exists.'));
            }
            if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('The order does not allow an invoice to be created.')
                );
            }

            $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $invoiceItems);
            if (!$invoice) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('We can\'t save the invoice right now.'));
            }
            if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an invoice without products.')
                );
            }
            $this->registry->register('current_invoice', $invoice);

            if (!empty($data['capture_case'])) {
                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase($data['capture_case']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
                $invoice->addComment(
                    $data['comment_text'],
                    isset($data['comment_customer_notify']),
                    isset($data['is_visible_on_front'])
                );
                $invoice->setCustomerNote($data['comment_text']);
                $invoice->setCustomerNoteNotify(isset($data['comment_customer_notify']));
            }

            $invoice->register();
            $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(!empty($data['send_email']));
            $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            $transactionSave = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction'
            )->addObject(
                $invoice
            )->addObject(
                $invoice->getOrder()
            );

            $shipment = false;
            if (!empty($data['do_shipment']) || (int)$invoice->getOrder()->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()) {
                $shipment = $this->_prepareShipment($invoice);
                if ($shipment) {
                    $transactionSave->addObject($shipment);
                }
            }
            $transactionSave->save();

            if (isset($shippingResponse) && $shippingResponse->hasErrors()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __(
                        'The invoice and the shipment  have been created. ' .
                        'The shipping label cannot be created now.'
                    )
                );
            } elseif (!empty($data['do_shipment'])) {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You created the invoice and shipment.'));
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The invoice has been created.'));
            }

            // send invoice/shipment emails
            try {
                if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
                    $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t send the invoice email right now.'));
            }
            if ($shipment) {
                try {
                    if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
                        $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t send the shipment right now.'));
                }
            }
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getCommentText(true);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t save the invoice right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
        }
    }
}
```